# How do I pass a variable Id from Javascript to a RenderAction in MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view that appears in a bootstrap modal, I want to pass an Id to this partial view so I can return some specific data via the controller.  Because I am passing an Id to the partial view, I need to handle it within the controller and so I created a `RenderAction` that contains an Id (for testing).

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("_TabsEdit", new { @id = 31 }); }
```

Here is my controller code:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult _TabsEdit(int Id)
{
    Tab tab = unitOfWork.TabRepository.GetByID(Id);
    return PartialView(tab);
}
```

The problem is that the Id will not always been the same, the Id is currently captured from different buttons using javascript.

```
<button class="btn" onclick="addToTab();" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_editTabs">Add to Tab</button>
```

The javascript is as follows, the id of the button with the `active` class is captured:

```
function addToTab() {
    let tab = $('#tabs li a.active');
    let tabId = $('#tabId');
    tabId.val(tab.data("id"));   
}
```

My question is, how do I pass this dynamic Id to my `RenderAction` to return specific results based on the parameter or is my approach to this incorrect?

Comment: RenderAction runs on the server not the client so *passing a variable Id from Javascript to a RenderAction in MVC* makes no sense what-so-ever.  Your best option is to dynamically load html via ajax.  Additionally, I highly recommend if you're using jQuery don't use onclick.  Take a moment and read [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

Comment: Thanks Erik, not sure why you marked this as a duplicate, the question you link is about sending a variable to a controller were as mine is more specific and related to RenderAction.  Please remove your flag.